# Compiler error using Camera.isSupported

Tags: actionscript-3, webcam

I'm coding an AS3 web app which needs to access the webcam. The webcam code works fine apart from my initial attempt to detect whether a webcam is plugged into the pc.

I'm trying to use Camera.isSupported as specified in the Adobe docs but I get a compiler error telling me

1119: Access of possibly undefined property isSupported through a reference with static type Class. BriefingScreen.as   /ADAPT_PSA/src  line 147    Flex Problem

Any ideas? I can get around this by compiling without strict checking but this seems a little clumsy...

Comment: please create a simple document class that traces `Camera.isSupported` and post the code.  are you targeting Flash Player 10.1 / AIR 2 or higher?

Comment: thanks - I hadn't realised Camera.isSupported was only introduced in 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting and using a SDK for at least Flash Player 10.1?

When you are targeting pre Flash player 10.1, then you could get the camera and check whether or not it is null.

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
if(camera!=null) {
    // Camera is present
}
```

You could also check on whether or not the list of camera name is greater than zero (as each available camera is listed in this list).

```
if(Camera.names.length>0) {
   // At least one camera is connected
}
```

But again, that is only necessary for pre Flash Player 10.1

Comment: thanks Paul - I've decided to use getCamera as you suggest as I suspect some of my target users will have older versions of flash player, and may be deterred by being forced to upgrade...